# How to migrate test plan (or test cases) from one VSTS to other VSTS?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I want to move my test plan which is created in one Azure DevOps (VSTS) to other Azure DevOps (VSTS).

I couldn't find any option in Azure DevOps. Copying test step by step takes a lot of time.

Does anyone know the option for this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in feature to migrate test plans across. There are 3rd party tools that can export/import or live-migrate them.

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration

Comment: I am looking at it, I cant tell how to run it for test plan migration? Is there a specific config file that I need to run?

Comment: @lavoizer https://nkdagility.com/learn/azure-devops-migration-tools/Reference/v1/Processors/TestPlansAndSuitesMigrationContext/

Comment: I actually did run that, thank you, however i am running into this error, not sure what it is about? Any clue or input would be helpful.

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element
at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)